# animateLayoutChanges="true" in BottomSheetView showing unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, animation, bottom-sheet

I have a `BottomSheetView` which has `animateLayoutChanges="true"`. Initially it shows up fine. But if change the `visibility` of a view (inside `BottomSheetView`) from `GONE` to `VISIBLE`, the app messes up calculations and my `BottomSheetView` moves to the top of the screen. i have tried setting `layout_gravity=bottom` at the root of the `BottomSheetView` layout. But no success.

Here I have the image of my `BottomSheetView` before changing the visibility of any view. (Click image for full size)

[image]

After I change the visibility of a view (`GONE` to `VISIBLE` or `VISIBLE` to `GONE`), my BottomSheetView moves to the top. (Click image for full size)

[image]

I guess, Android is messing up while making calculations about the measurement of view `width` and `height`. Any way to solve this??

I also tried to make my BottomSheetView extend fully to match the parent view, but somehow that is making the `height` of the `BottomSheetView` longer than the phone screen and in-tun creating scrolling issues.

**Expected solutions:**

1> Prevent `BottomSheetView` from changing its position even when the `visibility` of a view is changed.

OR

2>Make the `BottomSheetView` match parent so that it does not look bad after messing up with the calculations.

Answer (score 36):

The BottomSheetBehavior does not work well with `LayoutTransition` (`animateLayoutChanges="true"`) for now. I will work on a fix.

For now, you can use `Transition` instead. Something like this will fade the view inside and animate the size of the bottom sheet.

```
ViewGroup bottomSheet = ...;
View hidingView = ...;

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(bottomSheet);
hidingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You can refer to [Applying a Transition](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/transitions.html) for more information including how to customize the animation.

Comment: Perfect solution. Also, if one wants to change the duration for example, add as a 2nd argument to `beginDelayedTransition` the following transition: `new AutoTransition().setDuration(150)`

Comment: So here is the fix?
I'm using the last version of the library `com.android.support:design` and still happening..
Check here: https://github.com/extmkv/BottomSheetExample

Comment: Also still wondering if there is a fix yet. Is there an issue filed somewhere that we could watch?

Comment: Same here, also wondering if there is a bug created for this and whether it will ever get fixed.

Comment: @Yuichi Are there a fix available for this now.

Comment: For those trying to animate content change of BottomSheetDialog - you have to find the sheet view group like `dialog.findViewById<ViewGroup>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)`

Comment: 4 years passed since this issue reported, and it's still persists in 2021

Comment: going to be 6 years now

Answer (score 12):

I was running into the same issue and determined to find a fix. I was able to find the underlying cause but unfortunately I do not see a great  fix at the moment.

**The Cause:**
The problem occurs between the bottomsheet behavior and the LayoutTransition. When the LayoutTransition is created, it creates a OnLayoutChangeListener on the view so that it can capture its endValues and setup an animator with the proper values. This OnLayoutChangeListener is triggered in the bottomSheetBehavior's `onLayout()` call when it first calls `parent.onLayout(child)`. The parent will layout the child as it normally would, ignoring any offsets that the behavior would change later. The problem lies here. The values of the view at this point are captured by the OnLayoutChangeListener and stored in the animator. When the animation runs, it will animate to these values, not to where your behavior defines. Unfortunately, the LayoutTransition class does not give us access to the animators to allow updating of the end values.

**The Fix:**
Currently, I don't see an elegant fix that involves LayoutTransitions. I am going to submit a bug for a way to access and update  LayoutTransition animators. For now you can disable any layoutTransition on the parent container using `layoutTransition.setAnimateParentHierarchy(false)`. Then you can animate the change yourself. I'll update my answer with a working example as soon as I can.

Comment: Did you submit the bug? Did you find an elegant way?

Comment: >  I am going to submit a bug for a way to access and update LayoutTransition animators

Could you post the bug that you submitted? I would like to follow for updates :)

Comment: Issue is there, for anyone curious about it -https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2062

Answer (score 11):

I use this and I got to keep the animations!

```
 val transition = LayoutTransition()
 transition.setAnimateParentHierarchy(false)
 {Parent View which has animateLayoutChanges="true" }.layoutTransition = transition
```

Comment: Nice clean fix! I implemented it as: myView.layoutTransition = LayoutTransition()
    .apply { setAnimateParentHierarchy(false) }

Answer (score 8):

The question was asked more than two years ago, but unfortunately the problem persists.

I finally got a solution to keep the call to the `addView` and `removeView` functions in a BottomSheet, while having `animateLayoutChanges="true"`.

`BottomSheetBehavior` cannot calculate the correct height when it changes, so the height must remain the same. To do this, I set the height of the `BottomSheet` to `match_parent` and divide it into two children: the content and a `Space` that changes height according to the height of the content.

To best mimic the true behavior of a `BottomSheet`, you also need to add a TouchToDismiss view that darkens the background when the `BottomSheet` is extended but also to close the `BottomSheet` when the user presses outside the content.

Here's the code:

activity.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show bottom sheet"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/touch_to_dismiss"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#9000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/space"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_or_remove_another_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add another view"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/another_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Another view"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity.java

```
BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
View touchToDismiss;
LinearLayout bottomSheet;
Button showBottomSheet;
Space space;
LinearLayout bottomSheetContent;
Button addOrRemoveAnotherView;
TextView anotherView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    touchToDismiss = findViewById(R.id.touch_to_dismiss);
    touchToDismiss.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    touchToDismiss.setOnClickListener(this);

    bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN || newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                touchToDismiss.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                touchToDismiss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            touchToDismiss.setAlpha(getRealOffset());
        }
    });

    showBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.show_bottom_sheet);
    showBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(this);

    space = findViewById(R.id.space);

    bottomSheetContent = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_content);

    addOrRemoveAnotherView = findViewById(R.id.add_or_remove_another_view);
    addOrRemoveAnotherView.setOnClickListener(this);

    anotherView = findViewById(R.id.another_view);
    bottomSheetContent.removeView(anotherView);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == showBottomSheet)
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    else if (v == addOrRemoveAnotherView) {
        if (anotherView.getParent() == null)
            bottomSheetContent.addView(anotherView);
        else
            bottomSheetContent.removeView(anotherView);
    }
    else if (v == touchToDismiss)
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}

/**
 * Since the height does not change and remains at match_parent, it is required to calculate the true offset.
 * @return Real offset of the BottomSheet content.
 */
public float getRealOffset() {
    float num = (space.getHeight() + bottomSheetContent.getHeight()) - (bottomSheet.getY() + space.getHeight());

    float den = bottomSheetContent.getHeight();

    return (num / den);
}
```

This is the result obtained with this code:
[image: final result]

Hopefully it will be useful to someone since the problem is still there!

Answer (score 2):

In the BottomSheetDialog default layout ([design_bottom_sheet_dialog](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design/blob/master/res/layout/design_bottom_sheet_dialog.xml)) there is a **TOP** gravity on the dialog's `design_bottom_sheet` FrameLayout:

```
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
```

I don't really know why on **Bottom**SheetDialog gravity is top.

You need to create the same layout file (same content and name)  in your project and replace this line with:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
```

Comment: It didn't work with BottomSheetDialog having edittext. Weird behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

In our case, we were displaying a progress bar on a button component. This was hiding the button text and displaying progress bar. This was causing a jump in bottom sheet fragment. Using Invisible instead of Gone fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

If your view allows, make the visibility INVISIBLE instead of GONE.